# Which package contains /usr/bin/less for Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: apt, dpkg, less

As in the title. Neither `dpkg -S /usr/bin/less` nor `apt-file search /usr/bin/less` produces anything useful.

Does it mean that there's a bug or that less really doesn't come from any package?

(In case you're wondering why I need to know the answer, I find that the `less` is an old version 487 instead of [530](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107355/195370) that has a feature I want.)

```
$ which less
/usr/bin/less
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/less
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/less
$ apt-file search /usr/bin/less
colorized-logs: /usr/bin/lesstty
libcss-lessp-perl: /usr/bin/lessp
node-less: /usr/bin/lessc
```

Comment: Somewhat related (on [unix.se]): [How to find out which package installed a symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159004/how-to-find-out-which-package-installed-a-symlink)

Comment: Version 530 has not been packaged for Debian/Ubuntu. The volunteer who packaged `less` for Debian and Ubuntu has apparently ceased volunteering. [A new volunteer is welcome](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=925018).

Comment: Try `apt search '^less'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because `/usr/bin/less` is a symbolic link:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/less
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jul 21  2017 /usr/bin/less -> /bin/less
```

The latter is provided by package `less`

```
$ dpkg -S $(realpath $(which less))
less: /bin/less
```

---

The symbolic link is one of several created by the `postinst` script during package configuration:

```
case "$1" in
    configure)
        for file in lessfile lesspipe lesskey lessecho less; do
          if [ ! -e /usr/bin/$file ]; then
            ln -s /bin/$file /usr/bin/$file
          fi
        done
    .
    .
    .
```

(The same script installs `less` as the default `pager` under `update-alternatives`.)

Comment: Thanks. Does any package own the symlink? If so, why do the tools not care about the symlinks? If not how does Ubuntu know to remove the symlink? Is it just that the tools are limited in this sense? Perhaps Ubuntu knows to add/remove the symlinks as a post -installation/-uninstallation actions?

Comment: @Syncopated I have updated the answer with some information about the symlink

Comment: The dpkg database only shows you files that are managed directly by dpkg, it doesn't show you files that are managed by the maintainer scripts :(